# NLP: Pre-processing in doc2vec / word2vec

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

A few papers on the topics of word and document embeddings (word2vec, doc2vec) mention that they used the Stanford CoreNLP framework to tokenize/lemmatize/POS-tag the input words/sentences:

> The  corpora  were  lemmatized and POS-tagged with the Stanford CoreNLP (Manning  et  al.,  2014)  and  each  token  was  replaced with its lemma and POS tag

(http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/131/039/ecp17131039.pdf)

> For pre-processing, we tokenise and lowercase the words using Stanford CoreNLP

(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.05368.pdf)

So my questions are:

- Why does the first paper apply POS-tagging? Would each token then be replaced with something like `{lemma}_{POS}` and the whole thing used to train the model? Or are the tags used to filter tokens? 
  For example, gensims WikiCorpus applies lemmatization per default and then only keeps a few types of part of speech (verbs, nouns, etc.) and gets rid of the rest. So what is the recommended way?
- The quote from the second paper seems to me like they only split up words and then lowercase them. This is also what I first tried before I used WikiCorpus. In my opinion, this should give better results for document embeddings as most of POS types contribute to the meaning of a sentence. Am I right?

In the original doc2vec paper I did not find details about their pre-processing.

Comment: did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the answer is "it depends on what you are trying to accomplish!"

There isn't a recommended way per say, to pre-process text. To clean a text corpus, usually the first steps are `tokenization` and `lemmatization`. Next, to remove not important terms/tokens, you can remove `stop-words` or even apply `POS tags`, to be able to remove tokens based on their grammatical category, based on the assumption that some grammatical categories (such as adjectives), do not contain valuable information for modelling a topic for example. But this purely depends on the type of analysis you are going to follow after the pre-processing step.

For you second part of the question, as explained above, tokenisation and `lower case` tokens, are standard parts of the pre-processing routine. So I also suspect, that regardless of the ML algorithm used later on, your results will be better if you carefully pre-process your data. I am not sure whether POS tags contribute to the meaning of a sentence though.

Hope I provided some valuable feedback to your research. If not you could provide a code sample to further discuss this issue.